# Spring security does not behave properly when session is reset

Tags: spring, spring-security

I restart my server which essentially clears out all the contents of the session. Since the session has been cleared out the user can no longer be considered to be logged in. (JSESSIONID cookie remains with the browser)

But spring does not redirect to login unless I delete the JESSIONID cookie from the browser. 
My question is - Why does spring security rely on JESSIONID cookie and not on session?

This is my spring-security.xml configuration -

```
    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/portal/login*"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logoutSuccess*"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.css"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />    

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/portal/**"
            access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/portal/login.action"
            login-processing-url="/portal/loginProcess" default-target-url="/portal/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/portal/login.action?login_error=1" />

        <security:logout logout-url="/portal/logout"
            logout-success-url="/portal/login.action" />

    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>

            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT emailid AS username, password, IF(active = 'Y', true, false) AS enabled FROM users WHERE emailid = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority from authorities where username = ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: what happens if you don't delete cookie from web browser and server does not redirect you to logging page? does it behave as if you were logged in (you can see protected resources etc.) ?

Comment: @Poitrek Yes. It behaves as if user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

> I restart my server which essentially clears out all the contents of
>   the session. Since the session has been cleared out the user can no
>   longer be considered to be logged in.

According to your comment, that after server restart application behaves as if the user was logged in, I suspect that you have a session persistence enabled (it is enabled by default on Tomcat/JBoss), so you are actually logged in (the same JSESSIONID). Also, you probably loose your session content because objects that you put into session are not serializable.

According to Tomcat documentation (JBoss behaves similarly in this case):

> Disable Session Persistence As documented above, every web application
>   by default has standard manager implementation configured, and it
>   performs session persistence across restarts. To disable this
>   persistence feature, create a Context configuration file for your web
>   application and add the following element there:

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is - Why does spring security rely on JESSIONID cookie and
>   not on session

You must have enabled cookie based sessions. If you are using tomcat 7 you probably have something like this in your web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <!-- Disables URL-based sessions (no more 'jsessionid' in the URL using Tomcat) -->
  <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

remove it.